# How to determine BSSID from MAC Address

Tags: mac-address, ieee-802.11

As I know BSSID is derived from MAC Address, but I have no idea how it is derived and what pattern is used. Since there might be multiple BSSIDs from a device, I want to get all the BSSID that could be generated from the device, therefore I hope to understand the pattern of how BSSID is derived from a MAC Address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

> As I know BSSID is derived from MAC Address, but I have no idea how it is derived and what pattern is used.

It is possible, but not any sort of requirement. It is simply often just easier for vendors to assign consecutive addresses from their OUI space for use in the access point.

But there it is possible and even likely that there is no correlation for example between the wired MAC address and the addresses used by the AP for BSSIDs.

As such, there is no "pattern" as how a manufacturer chooses to use their OUI addresses is entirely up to them and each vendor may do it differently.

Comment: I wanted to use the MAC address to generate a key from it, but usually BSSID is different compare to the MAC address of the device therefore there will be difference in the person who generate the key and the person who take the BSSID to generate the key.